# Does a sonar less/css plugin exsit?

Tags: css, less, sonarqube

I have been talking to less/css developers and they would like to do static code analysis on there less code. I was wondering if there is a plugin for sonar that can do this analysis on the less code instead of the generated css code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SonarQube CSS plugin now supports Less. See https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin/releases/tag/2.2

Comment: That link returns a 404 now -- the plugin appears to have disappeared without a trace. What happened?

Answer (score 1):

There is no less plugin. The css plugin could be extended (it has an unfinished sass parser already) to support less as well

Comment: Do you know if sonar has one?

Comment: What do you mean? sonar is sonarqube

Comment: ok so I was talking about sonarqube not jenkins. Jenkins has nothing to do with static code analysis in its own.

Comment: I know, just put in the wrong title, so just checking